# Is it correct to say "are you logged in" or "have you logged in"?

Tags: causative-have

Which is the correct way of asking the question
"Are you logged in"?
Or
"Have you logged in"?

Comment: Are they supposed to be logged in when you ask the question?

Comment: Both are grammatical and understandable.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct - it ultimately depends on the question that you wish to ask.

If you were to ask:

> Are you logged in?

Then you are asking whether the user is currently logged into a particular system at the present moment.

Whereas, if you were to ask:

> Have you logged in?

Then you are asking whether, at some point in time, the user has performed the action of logging into a particular system.